# Go to parent and count the number of childs in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have like

```
<Father>
<child1/>
<child2/>
<child3/>
<child4/>
</Father>
```

I am at `<child1>` node.(or in any other child node.) now I need to count the number of childs Father has. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `count(../*)` help? It counts the child elements of the parent of the context node.